# Differential form on complex torus

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, several-complex-variables

Suppose $T= \mathbb{C}^n/\Gamma$ is a $n$-dim complex torus.

How to prove that every exact $2$-form which has no $(0,2)$ component must be the image of a $(1,0)$ form?

Is every torus Kahler?

If the torus is Kahler, can we use hodge decomposition to prove it?

Comment: Every T-invariant Kahler structure $\omega$ on complex torus $T^\mathbb C$ is exact and has a T-invariant potential
function $F$. The T-action preserving $\omega$ is Hamiltonian. See this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02921824

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every torus are Kahler: the standard form $\omega = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n dz^i \wedge d\bar z ^i$ descends to a Kahler form on the torus. Let $\alpha$ be a 1 form. Write

$$\alpha = \alpha^{1,0} + \alpha^{0,1}$$

so 
$$d \alpha = d\alpha^{1,0} + d\alpha^{0,1}$$

If $d\alpha$ has no $(0,2)$ component, then $d\alpha^{0,1}$ is a $(1,1)$ form and the $\partial \bar\partial$-lemma tells us that there is a function $\phi$ such that

$$d\alpha = \partial \bar\partial \phi = - \bar \partial \partial \phi = -d \partial \phi$$

Thus

$$d\alpha = d\big(\alpha^{1,0} - \partial \phi\big)$$

and $\alpha^{1,0} - \partial \phi$ is a $(1,0)$ form.

Comment: Is there a reference for the $\partial \bar{\partial}$-lemma? Thanks!

Comment: @mqx: The lemma can be found in Complex geometry by D. Huybrechts (p.128)